# ALTER TABLE sql command in eloquent

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent

Does anyone know how to translate this sql command in eloquent ? -> ALTER TABLE some_table AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ?

In my seeder file I'd like to have that command to reset the AI counter after deleting data in table.

Comment: Did my answer work for you?